# How to eliminate 'braces on new line' using Intellij search and replace pattern?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, code-inspection, inspection, structural-search

I'm trying to find all if statements where the curly brackets are written in a new line using the following search and replace template:

Search template:

```
if ($Expr$)
{
    $ThenStatements$;
}
else
{
    $ElseStatements$;
}
```

Replace template:

```
if ($Expr$) {
    $ThenStatements$;
}
else {
    $ElseStatements$;
}
```

The problem i'm facing if that the template engine does not differentiate between both templates. It offers me to replace the search template with the correct one, but it also detects 'correct' templates as faulty ones.

Is there a way around this using some kind of regex?

Edit:
Working on Android Studio. I'm trying to generate a set of lint rules for my companies Code Styling conventions which will appear as warnings or errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structural Search & Replace is designed for searching code no matter how it's formatted. Therefore your usecase is not really supported. However with a bit of a hack it is possible to get what you want out of it.

Start with your search template and add the following Groovy script constraints to the `$Expr$` variable:

```
import com.intellij.psi.*
import com.intellij.openapi.editor.Document

PsiDocumentManager dm = PsiDocumentManager.getInstance(__context__.project)
Document d = dm.getDocument(__context__.containingFile)
PsiIfStatement is = __context__.parent
if (is.thenBranch != null && is.thenBranch.text.startsWith("{")) {
  if (d.getLineNumber(is.thenBranch.textOffset) > d.getLineNumber(is.RParenth.textOffset))
    return true
}
if (is.elseBranch != null && is.elseBranch.text.startsWith("{")) {
  if (d.getLineNumber(is.elseBranch.textOffset) > d.getLineNumber(is.elseElement.textOffset))
    return true;
}
return false
```

This script checks if the then branch `{` is on a line greater than the `)` of the if statement, or if the else branch `{` is on a line greater than the `else` keyword, or returns `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the right tool for the job is the code formatter.

I'm presuming this is Java we're talking about.

Adjust the formatter settings:

- go to Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> (tab) Wrapping and Braces
- set the item Braces Placement / Other to: End of line
- check the preview if its the setting you want
- click OK

Format (all) the code:

- select the root package
- click Alt+L (menu: Code -> Reformat Code)
- the Reformat Code dialog appears, click OK

All the code should be reformatted according to the rules.

Comment: The formatting tool is great. But i'm not sure It's what I'm looking for. I'm trying to generate a set of lint rules that will appear as warning/error markers in the IDEs gutter.

Comment: Your issue seems to be a formatting problem, not a static code analysis problem (for which lint is primarily used). You don't want to change the code to improve formatting, but only want to report the problem?

Comment: I thought of enforcing our code conventions with lint. Formatting would fix the problems once but would still allow 'bad' code to be committed.

Comment: You should checkout [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) - it does what you want and can be installed both in IDEs and CI servers.

Comment: Yup, Thanks Marko. I did in fact end up integrating Checkstyle.  I found this project to be quite helpful https://github.com/vincentbrison/vb-android-app-quality